# Creating property to store two values

Tags: delphi

Using Delphi 10 I have two values `work_start` and `work_finish` of type `TTime` that I need to read and write from database table so I though to create a property for each one like that

```
private
    fWorkStart: TTime;
    function GetWS: TTime;
    procedure SetWS(const Value: TTime);
  Public 
    property WorkStart: TTime read GetWS write SetWS;

  ....

  procedure MyClass.SetWS(const Value: TTime);
begin
  fWorkStart := value;

  mydataset.Edit;
  mydataset.FieldByName('work_start').AsDateTime := fWorkStart;
  mydataset.Post;
end;

function MyClass.GetWS: TTime;
begin
  if mydataset.FieldByName('work_start').IsNull then
    fWorkStart := encodetime(6,0,0,0)
  else
    fWorkStart := mydataset.FieldByName('work_start').AsDateTime;

  result := fWorkStart;
end;
```

WorkFinish property is the same. So is there a way to create one property for both times or my code is fine ?

Comment: You need two separate properties. Your code looks fine.

Comment: If they go together put them in a record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible:

```
//Define a record to hold both
type
  TTimeRange = record
    StartTime: TTime;
    EndTime: TTime;
  end;

//And have your property use the record
property WorkHours: TTimeRange read GetWorkHours write SetWorkHours;
```

However, this would force clients of your class to interact using the record structure. Basically the complications you'd encounter outweigh the small benefit you'd gain.

So I don't recommend it.
(Although it's worth remembering the technique because in other scenarios it may prove more useful.)

---

As for your code:

- Handling of properties is fine. Although in the code you've presented `fWorkStart` is redundant.
- I'd caution against `Edit` and `Post` within your property writer. Apart from the fact that updating 1 field at a time in the Db would be highly inefficient, your method has unexpected side-effects. (And can you always assume edit is the right choice and not insert?)
- In your property reader, assuming NULL == 6:00 is not a good idea. NULL has very specific meaning that the value is unknown/unassigned. Defaulting it in the wrong place leads to being unable to tell the difference between 6:00 and NULL. (I'm not saying never default a null; just understand the implications.)

Comment: @Wel I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. You can do whatever you need to within `SetWorkHours`. If you're asking about database fields, the general approach is `Edit` or `Insert` then set all fields you want to change on the current row. And finally `Post` to perform all updates at the same time.

Comment: @CraigYoung You say that using of records would force users to always interact only with records. That is not entirely true. It is true that the property would be expecting a whole record as a parameter passed to it. But you can always declare two more properties where each of them is accessing separate record fields using getter and setter methods. This way you get ability to read/write whole record or individual fields as needed.

Comment: @SilverWarior You're the one who decided to add the word "always". Of course you can add a secondary method of interfacing; at the cost of simplicity. You also now need to ensure both client interfaces behave consistently with each other; permutations are probably manageable with 2 attributes; but it can quickly get out of hand.

Answer (score 4):

[Craig's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40965257/33732) demonstrates record properties, which means you have a single property that gets set as a unit; you can't set the start and finish times independently. [Dawood's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40976111/33732) demonstrates an array property, which allows independent accesses, but imposes cumbersome bracket notation on the consumer. [Kobik's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40964150/creating-property-to-store-two-values#comment69165751_40976111) improves the semantics, but we can do even better using [*index specifiers*](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Properties#Index_Specifiers).

First, define an enum to represent the two kinds of times:

```
type
  TWorkTime = (wtStart, wtFinish);
```

Use those values in your property declarations, and provide an extra parameter to your property accessors to represent the index:

```
private
  FWorkTime: :array[TWorkTime] of TTime;
  function GetWT(Index: TWorkTime): TTime;
  procedure SetWT(Index: TWorkTime; const Value: TTime);
public 
  property WorkStart: TTime index wsStart read GetWT write SetWT;
  property WorkFinish: TTime index wsFinish read GetWT write SetWT;
```

To reduce [the bloat Craig warns about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40964150/creating-property-to-store-two-values#comment69176580_40976111) in your accessors, you can define another array with the corresponding fields names, which lets you avoid duplicating code for your different fields:

```
const
  FieldNames: array[TWorkTime] of string = (
    'work_start',
    'work_finish'
  );

function MyClass.GetWT(Index: TWorkTime): TTime;
begin
  if mydataset.FieldByName(FieldName[Index]).IsNull then
    FWorkTime[Index] := EncodeTime(6, 0, 0, 0)
  else
    FWorkTime[Index] := mydataset.FieldByName(FieldNames[Index]).AsDateTime;
  Result := FWorkTime[Index];
end;
```

Comment: While I must congratulate you on putting together the cleanest implementation of dawood's idea; I can't help the sinking feeling that this is a few small steps from becoming a "super object" with `GetTimeField`, `SetTimeField`, `GetStringField`, `SetStringField`, `GetIntField`, `SetIntField`, `GetDoubleField`, etc. In which case it would just be a meta-layer on top the existing Delphi framework; more like a solution looking for a problem. Anyway +1 for showing some good techniques. (PS: I doubt `NULL implies 06:00` can be assumed for all time fields - it's a rabbit warren.)

Answer (score 1):

yes you can use indexed properties

```
property WorkTime[IsStart: Boolean]: TDataTime read GetWorkTime write SetWorkTime;

  procedure MyClass.SetWorkTime(IsStart: Boolean;const value: TDataTime);
begin
  mydataset.Edit;
  if IsStart then
    mydataset.FieldByName('work_start').AsDateTime := value else
    mydataset.FieldByName('work_Finish').AsDateTime := value;
  mydataset.Post;
end;

function MyClass.GetWorkTime(IsStart: Boolean): TTime;
begin
  if IsStart then
    Begin
      if mydataset.FieldByName('work_start').IsNull then
        fWorkStart := encodetime(6,0,0,0)
      else
       fWorkStart := mydataset.FieldByName('work_start').AsDateTime;
       result := fWorkStart;
    end else
    begin
      if mydataset.FieldByName('work_finish').IsNull then
        fWorkfinish := encodetime(6,0,0,0)
      else
       fWorkfinish := mydataset.FieldByName('work_finish').AsDateTime;
       result := fWorkfinish;
    end
end;
```

Comment: good idea +1. implementation could be better IMO. e.g. use `TWorkTime = (wtStart, wtFinish)` as index, and use internal field `fWorkTime: array[TWorkTime]` instead of two, which will make `GetWorkTime` not repeating code for both cases.

Comment: @kobik please put your idea in a complete answer I would like to see it.

Comment: Think about what this design will look like in client code: `obj.WorkTime[True] := EncodeTime(...); obj.WorkTime[False] := EncodeTime(...); ` and conversely a time looks like `Val := obj.WorkTime[True];` Client code is not very readable. You would have to implement @kobik 's idea to make the code readable; but would still suffer all the problems described in my answer.

Comment: Furthermore, you haven't really simplified the code. All you're achieving is bundling it all in one of 2 bloated methods. Consider @kobik 's comment (which would be an improvement) in a more extreme case by having the enum include some process flow timestamps: `(wtStart, wtFinish, wtCreated, wtUpdated, wtApproved)`. Now imagine the code inside `GetWorkTime` and `SetWorkTime`. It gets bloated for no real benefit. The design violates Open Close Principle and Single Responsibility Principle. Conclusion: ***I strongly don't recommend it.***